# How to set paths on JavaFX for a local project

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I want to make a local JavaFX application but I don't know how to set the paths to the files so when I build the jar I won't have any problem.

I've built the jar and tried to fix as many errors as I could but I'm still having some that I can't fix.

Here is a [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms6Ma.png) of the source folder.

These are the errors I have

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
file:/D:/Users/eebal/IdeaProjects/Recetario/out/artifacts/Recetario/Recetario.jar!/sample/home.fxml

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2848)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at sample.Main.start(Main.java:21)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
        ... 20 more
Exception running application sample.Main

D:\Users\eebal\IdeaProjects\Recetario\out\artifacts\Recetario>java -jar Recetario.jar
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
file:/D:/Users/eebal/IdeaProjects/Recetario/out/artifacts/Recetario/Recetario.jar!/sample/home.fxml

        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2848)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at sample.Main.start(Main.java:21)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
        ... 20 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

This is the 21st line at Main `Parent home = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("home.fxml"));`

Answer (score 0):

Your error log says `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton`. This means the fxml could not get loaded because the class `JFXButton` could not been found. I think there is a problem with your library imports of jfoenix or you forgot to include the JFXButton import in your FXML file.

Comment: *"or you forgot to include the JFXButton import in your FXML file"* How would `FXMLLoader` come up with the correct fully qualified class name in this case???

Comment: Good point. I was just thinking of stuff I would check in this case.